# How do I add rate widget to certain content type?

Tags: nodes, rating

I have a certain content type I want users to be able to rate. I decided to go with the rate module, since I want to be able to change the value of each star.

My problem is I don't know how to add the certain rate widget to a content type. In widget settings there are no checkboxes in the "Node types" option. Screenshot below.
[image: Rate widget Node types section missing checkboxes]

Comment: Don't know what causes this, since when I try the module with a clean install of Drupal, everything works as expected. Thats what I probably have to do in this case.. start over with a clean install.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot find a clear reason for why this happened. The best answer I can give to someone with the same problem (doesn't seem to be a common problem at all) is to start over with a clean Drupal install.